# getting Current script version using Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am aware of the versioning that can be done using "Manage Version". Is there a way available to get/fetch the current version of the Spreadsheet script in/using Apps script .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean "Can we programmatically retrieve the script version number?", the answer is no. There is an outstanding request for this, in [Issue 1369](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369), so visit the issue tracker and star it to indicate your own interest.

Perhaps you mean "Can we programmatically retrieve the most recent source code?"

You can [Import and Export](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) Stand-alone script files through the Drive SDK. In Apps Script, this can be accomplished using [UrlFetch Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/).

There is no way at this time to retrieve the source of container-bound scripts, except through the Script Editor. (See [Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#limitations).)

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the way to get the script version number programatically. Thanks for your suggestion I have starred the issue 1369, it was exactly the same I wanted to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving a dead one here but others might find this as I have still searching for a solution.

Resolution of Issue 1369 as linked in the other answer is:

```
Jan 22, 2018 12:09PM 
Marked as fixed, reassigned to ti...@google.com.
As Federico states, with the new Apps Script API you can get script versions.

Also, with the CLI (github.com/google/clasp), you can get version info with:

    clasp versions
```

this means we can fetch a list of versions but I still have not found a way of programmatically getting the version number and description from within a script.

Comment: I think they're suggesting you can use the AppScript UrlFetchApp API (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to invoke the Apps Script REST API (e.g., https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list) to get the versions of the script.  So technically possible, but there are OAuth hurdles to jump through.